# Автоматическое добавления значения в БД

Tags: c#

Ребята, может кто сталкивался с такой задачей. Создал форму для добавления данных в БД.
В таблице есть поля:
id, Name и CerNambe
где id идет порядковым номером и автоматически увеличивается на 1, ну Name понятно, а вот CerNambe имеет значение (n-Р/2022, где n-порядковый номер). Как сделать чтоб при добавлении новой записи автоматически менялось только значение n. То есть хочу запретить пользователю вручную вводить номер.

Comment: trigger *(нужно ещё 3 символа...)*

Comment: автоинкремент sql

Comment: @Igor, Можно немного подробнее?

Comment: @NMD, мне кажется это не подойдет, может быть пустые значения. То есть не для каждого Name  будет присвоено значение CerNambe

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать поле вычисляемым. Но нужно еще, как я понимаю, год указывать, а значит его или дату нужно хранить.

Второй вариант: Сделать скалярную функцию, которая по году и Id сделает название. Эту функцию указать в качестве дефолтной.

Третий вариант: Сделать процедуру, которая по нужному правилу соберет название и добавит как новую строку в таблицу.

Comment: А вы не могли бы чуть чуть подтолкнуть в нужном направлении?

Comment: Тут три направления, из которых можно выбрать понравившееся.